# GWT JSNI - problem passing Strings

Tags: gwt, jsni

I'm trying to provide some function hooks in my GWT project:

```
private TextBox hello = new TextBox();
private void helloMethod(String from) { hello.setText(from); }
private native void publish() /*-{
 $wnd.setText = $entry(this.@com.example.my.Class::helloMethod(Ljava/lang/String;));
}-*/;
```

`publish()` being called in `onModuleLoad()`.  But this doesn't work, providing no feedback as to why in the dev console.  I've also tried:

```
private native void publish() /*-{
 $wnd.setText = function(from) {
  alert(from);
  this.@com.example.my.Class::helloMethod(Ljava/lang/String;)(from);
 }
}-*/;
```

which will toss a `java.lang.ClassCastException` in the FireBug console, though the `alert` fires just fine.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
private native void publish(EntryPoint p) /*-{
 $wnd.setText = function(from) {
  alert(from);
  p.@com.example.my.Class::helloMethod(Ljava/lang/String;)(from);
 }
}-*/;
```

Could you give this code a try?

Comment: very nice - I think I prefer this over the `var that = this` syntax.

Comment: I too prefer this.  I also prefer to designate such methods as `static` to further signify that they don't rely on the "Java-style" `this`.

Answer (score 7):

`helloMethod` is an instance method, and as such it requires the `this` reference to be set, when it is *called*. Your first example doesn't do this at call time. Your second example attempts to do this, but there's a little mistake, which one can make easily in JavaScript: The `this` reference in

```
$wnd.setText = function(from) {
  this.@com.example.my.Class::helloMethod(Ljava/lang/String;)(from);
};
```

points to the function itself. To avoid this, you'll have to do something like:

```
var that = this;
$wnd.setText = function(from) {
  that.@com.example.my.Class::helloMethod(Ljava/lang/String;)(from);
};
```

Or better:

```
var that = this;
$wnd.setText = $entry(function(from) {
  that.@com.example.my.Class::helloMethod(Ljava/lang/String;)(from)
});
```

Comment: Chris, thanks - both your corrections work like a charm.  You say the second one is better - can you clarify why?

Comment: @Carl: Sure, the [dev guide on JSNI](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#sharing) says about `$entry`: "This implicitly-defined function ensures that the Java-derived method is executed with the uncaught exception handler installed and pumps a number of other utility services. The $entry function is reentrant-safe and should be used anywhere that GWT-derived JavaScript may be called into from a non-GWT context." BTW, the `var that = this;` line is a typical JavaScript idiom (see eg this [article](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html)).

Comment: weeell, I was hoping you'd actually explain what that quote from the dev guide *meant* (I'd already read it).  I'm familiar with the `var that = this;` idiom, but going with @ykartal's solution makes it possible to make `publish` static - usually an early step towards being able to generify/extract/otherwise relocate methods.

Comment: @Carl: I'm awful at mind reading over the internet. I'm a little bit hesitant now to explain the uncaught exception handler, if you understand... In any case, this would deserve a separate question.

Comment: great post, do you have any idea why using `$wnd.setText = $entry(that.@com.example.my.Class::helloMethod(Ljava/lang/String;));` throws class cast exception (JavaScriptObject to com.example.my.Class)?