# GWT calling java method from javascript not working

Tags: gwt, gwt2, jsni

I have a requirement where I have to call a java GWT method from a javascript but it does not work. No exception is thrown but the application hangs somewhere and the code doesn't run. The application works fine when I don't make that call. My GWT-Compile is sucessful. I am testing in dev mode in Firefox.

My code is something like this -

```
class CPClass {

    public native void jsCallViewDocument(String objectId)/*-{
        $wnd.jsCallViewDocument = 
            $entry(this.@com.srre.g0a.client.presenter.impl.viewdoc.CPClass::testJS(Ljava/lang/String;)(objectId));
    }-*/;

    private void testJS(String objectId) {
        SC.say("Call successfull" + objectId);
    }

    private void setDocName(ListGridRecord newRecord, someDTO currDocInfo) {

        String anchorTag = "<a href ='#' onclick = \"javascript:jsCallViewDocument('" 
            +  currDocInfo.getDocName() + "')\">" + currDocInfo.getDocName() + "</a>";

        newRecord.setAttribute(Display.GRID_FIELD_DOC_NAME, anchorTag);
    }

}
```

Till now I have used JSNI to make simple calls like $wnd.close() or $wnd.alert(), so I might be missing something. Does my class (where the Native method and the method to be called are defined) need to extend JavaScriptObject or does that native method to be registered first or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've got a bit confused here.

Your code as it is will only work if you have already invoked `jsCallViewDocument()` from your Java code before the link is clicked -- otherwise the `$wnd.jsCallViewDocument` function will not exist.

It would make no sense in that case to pass the string in to the function.

What you probably want instead is a function like this:

```
public static native void setupJsCallViewDocument(CPClass p) /*-{
    var fn = function(objectId) {
        // invoke our (Java) testJS function, passing objectId as a parameter
        $entry(
           p.@com.srre.g0a.client.presenter.impl.viewdoc.CPClass::testJS(Ljava/lang/String;)(objectId)
        );
    };

    // assign this function to the global jsCallViewDocument
    $wnd.jsCallViewDocument = fn;
}-*/;
```

Now in your `setDocName` function:

```
private void setDocName(ListGridRecord newRecord, someDTO currDocInfo) {
    // set up the native function call
    setupJsCallViewDocument(this);

    String anchorTag = "<a href ='#' onclick = \"javascript:jsCallViewDocument('" 
        +  currDocInfo.getDocName() + "')\">" + currDocInfo.getDocName() + "</a>";

    newRecord.setAttribute(Display.GRID_FIELD_DOC_NAME, anchorTag);
}
```

Comment: I already invoked it. Your reason is not correct but your code is correct. I tested and found out that using "this." directly was the cause of the problem. Assigning it and using it solved the prob. var currentPage = this; but google's site also uses this.@something so why it didn't work is confusing? Also the $entry is not needed. Even removing it worked the same way. But anyways ur code contains it so I marked it correct.

Comment: @weakstudent Really?  I think my reason is correct; you seem to be entirely confused about how JSNI methods work, and how Javascript first-class functions work.  Your initial code was wrong because it was assigning `$wnd.jsCallViewDocument` to the `$entry()` wrapper which does not accept a parameter.  You were also passing a parameter unnecessarily into the native method.  You need to learn more about these subjects before writing more JSNI code like this -- in particular you need to understand why your original code was wrong.

Comment: `$entry` is required for calling into Java from JSNI code, see this comment for more:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234735/gwt-jsni-problem-passing-strings#comment5894088_5235580   I also suggest you google "Getting to really know GWT" for two excellent blogs about JSNI.  Finally, I suggest you read Douglas Crockford for the grounding in Javascript you need to use GWT and JSNI effectively.

Comment: sorry for my comment. I accept and understand those parts which you have mentioned in your first comments were also wrong. Somehow I didn't realize it. This was my first JSNI code so I am learning. Thank You! +1, for the pointing out the mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `javascript:` in `onClick` attribute  (as opposed to `href` attribute)

switch to:

```
String anchorTag = "<a href ='#' onclick = \"jsCallViewDocument('" 
        +  currDocInfo.getDocName() + "')\">" + currDocInfo.getDocName() + "</a>";
```

or:

```
String anchorTag = "<a href = \"javascript:jsCallViewDocument('" 
        +  currDocInfo.getDocName() + "')\">" + currDocInfo.getDocName() + "</a>";
```

by the way why not assign event listener in java gwt code?

Comment: Tomasz, Removed javascript: but that doesn't make any difference. In my case I have to make a link inside a Listgrid column(document name) which should call a custom method based on the document name clicked. and it should appear as Hyperlink so don't think event listener can work here. Here if I call jsCallViewDocument("some string") from my code it works. But when I click on the links that appear no alert box appears.

Comment: @weakstudent: you're right, if you are forced to return string rather than element then jsni seems to be the only solution.

Comment: when I create a method  public native void myTest()/*-{
  $wnd.jsCallViewDocument('0911');
 }-*/; and call myTest(). It says "Uncaught JavaScript exception [window.jsCallViewDocument is not a function]" . I think I have to register jsCallViewDocument() first since it is an anonymous method and needs to be parsed at runtime before it is called from Javascript.

Comment: What you've posted is true but not relevant to this guy's problem